# Changing URL for JSON calls to ASMX web service

Tags: url, asmx

We are making calls from our web app to a 'local' ASMX web service via JSON. I.e. the service is located in the same application.

The URL is configurable. When we change the URL, the call to the JSON service no longer works. We can see via fiddler that the URL is being called and appears correct. 
We can also retrieve the WSDL via the new URL.

Are there any settings hard wired into an ASMX service that we might have missed?

Comment: Do you make a cross-domain call with your new URL ?

Comment: Nope, the call is to the same server from which the calling page was served.